# #include file Directive not working

Tags: asp-classic

So I got this new site to take care of: http://www.kineformeconcept.com/mtl/index.shtml

The menu does not display anymore ever since the client moved is hosting location.

I've never used the #include file="whatever.html" directive.

I now it's an ASP directive, but I've never worked with ASP. Where should I start?

If anybody want to check out the code, it's at line 66:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ededee"><!--#include file="menu.html" --></td>
```

Comment: The new host is not supporting classic ASP, it's simple as that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - assuming it's even written in ASP. I'm starting to think that may not be the case.

Comment: @AnonJr that's classic ASP syntax and it sounds like it used to work on the previous host.

Comment: Do you get any error displayed ? If not what's printed in the rendered page?

Comment: as AnonJr points out below, the #indlude file and #include virtual directives are supported by Classic ASP, but this does not necessarily mean that it is an ASP site, in fact it more than likely isn't.  Find out if your server supports, or can support server side includes. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

Answer (score 1):

The `#include` directive is not a part of ASP per-se - it is a server directive, part of the web server itself and independent of the scripting language you are using.

If it worked on one server, and stopped working on the new server, then the most likely culprit is a mis-configured server.*

- If you are hosting it yourself, where to look to fix it will depend
  on the server software you are using and which version of that
  software you are using.
- If you are not hosting it yourself, you may need to contact your host
  about enabling the appropriate features.

The assumption so far has been that you are using ASP-Classic because that is what the question is tagged as, and you mention ASP in the question itself... but your link is to an `.shtml` page and the content of the question leads me to believe it's just static HTML with some `#include` statements.

---

Semi-random aside - it shouldn't matter, but if you've moved to a more ...particular... server software, it may just be fussing about the lack of space between the `<!--` and the `#include`. Instead of:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ededee"><!--#include file="menu.html" --></td>
```

Put:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ededee"><!-- #include file="menu.html" --></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The filename of your page is `.shtml`

It should be `.asp`, then `#include file` or `#include virtual` should work.

Comment: Most servers are set up to recognize `.shtml` files as including server directives, and will process them. it's what the `.shtml` extension is for - plain HTML w/ includes and other server directives, and no need to run through additional parsers.

Comment: Apache servers are usually set up to recognise .shtml but I don't think this is the case with IIS, (and it must be IIS if it's running ASP).  So yes, changing the .shtml extensions to .asp should work.  If this would mean trawling through the site to change loads of links then an alternative would be to map the .shtml extension to asp.dll through Handler Mappings in IIS Manager

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the extension to .asp did not work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @John - IIS can be set up to recognize `.shtml`, and most hosts I have used have it enabled by default. Some do not, and I seem to recall newer versions of IIS requiring you to enable any form of dynamic content - hence my original answer of a mis-configured server.

Answer (score 0):

Your new host is not supporting classic ASP. However, for such a simple thing you don't really need the power of classic ASP. You can use jQuery to easily load the menu into the table cell.

First, give unique id to the cell:

```
<td id="MenuCell" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ededee">
```

Now include jQuery library in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And finally add this code to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MenuCell").load("menu.html");
});
</script>
```

Done, you'll now see the menu in place, no server side code needed.

Comment: Yeah... I didn't want to have to go through all that trouble. The site is pretty old school. If I go with this route, I'll have to do that on all the pages. Bummer!

Comment: @PMaly you can have the JS code in separate file then just have `<script type="text/javascript" src="LoadMenu.js"></script>` if it's of any help.